# Firestore emulator and request.auth.email generating a 'Property email is undefined on object' error

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, firebase-cli

Thanks to the https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDulvfBpzZE great resource, I installed firestore emulator and my testing environment, everything went fine except when I came to test the following rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function invitationIsForMe(destEmail) {
        return request.auth.email == destEmail; 
    }

    match /invitations/{inviteId} {
        allow read, delete: if invitationIsForMe(resource.destEmail);
    }
}
```

Which generate an error in the test:
***FirebaseError:
Property email is undefined on object.***

The test is as follow:

```
const me = {uid: 'myuserid', email: 'me@foo.bar'};

const getDb = (auth) => {
    return firebase.initializeTestApp({projectId: YORGA_PROJECT_ID, auth}).firestore();
}

describe('firestore structure and rules', () => {
    it("Can read an invitation sent to me", async () => {
        const db = getDb(me);
        const testDoc = db.collection('invitations').where('destEmail', '==', me.email);
        await firebase.assertSucceeds(testDoc.get());
    })
}
```

If I test it with request.auth.uid, it's working (but that's not the logic I'm looking for).
So my question: is it a firestore emulator limitation ? I hope it's not and it's just me, but if it's the case I think the example given with a uid and an email for auth in initializing the testing base is a bit confusing so it's worth a warning.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to establish the authenticated user's email address.  It's merely requiring one, then failing because it's not actually set for the simulated user.

Comment: keep in mind that the arguments require to be named on the `initializeTestApp` function have you tried by having it like this: `return firebase.initializeTestApp({projectId: YORGA_PROJECT_ID, auth: auth}).firestore();`

Comment: Hi Doug, thank you. I though I was doing that by calingl getDb with 'me', which contains an email address. Hi José, thank you, actually I use the short notation {auth} for {auth: auth}, as per es6. I just tested  it with full regular syntax and same bug.